# Opening *.py file "created initially by Tkinter" in QT design and convert it to *.ui

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt

I started my design *.py with Tkinter; but I need to resume it with QT designer. Is it possible to import the *.py file into QT and resume what I was doing?

Comment: Another question; is it a kind of silliness to build a tool with Tkinter instead of using PyQT or GTK ?

Comment: @MohamedEL-Zonkoli, Tkinter is meant to be simple enough to start with. If you want the _true power_ of world-famous framework, then use PyQT.

Comment: Tkinter, GTK, and Qt all work fine with Python. Which is better? *Shrug*. It depends on what you're doing and personal preference. If you have a Tkinter app, and that's working: stick with it. If you don't like it or are running into problems: try something else, and see how that works. In the end, the only really good way to make this judgement is to try it all *for yourself* so you can make the best judgement what is the best solution *in this particular case*.

Comment: _"is it a kind of silliness to build a tool with Tkinter instead of using PyQT or GTK "_ - no, especially if you're just starting to learn GUI programming. Tkinter is a perfectly fine toolkit for many common tasks. I'm not sure what the other comment about "True power" means, because Tkinter is quite powerful, likely more powerful than you will need.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Sorry :-(

Qt Designer is XML based. Consider what would be required to convert a TKinter app to Qt. You'd have to analyse the Python source code including all the logic, and then try to determine the logic to see which elements are actually displayed. For example, I could do:

```
  if third_tuesday_of_the_month_and_full_moon():
      tk.Label(...)
```

How should this be imported? Should we ask? Should we assume something?

Plus:

- Not all Tkinter widgets and options for them have something that maps 1-to-1 with what Qt has.
- Some programming paradigms are quite different from Tkinter and Qt. You can't just convert this automatically.

So you'll have to start over I'm afraid.

Comment: Agree.. Thanks for the quick reply.. Anyways I'm a Py beginner and started working on my tool some weeks ago; then after I discovered that I could build it in a much easier way.. :) Is there anybody still using Tkinter on the earth except me? :)

Comment: @MohamedEL-Zonkoli No, I use Tkinter, and if you look at the [tag:tkinter] tag you'll there are plenty of other folk using it.

Comment: @MohamedEL-Zonkoli: lots of people use tkinter. Over 10,000 questions are tagged with tkinter on stackoverflow -- clearly people are using it. For most needs, tkinter is an absolutely fantastic tool, and perfect for learning GUI programming.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley @ Carpetsmoker  Thank you so much :)